Plotly - Renormalise data in response to zooming in on plotly figure
I have some data like:
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Example data
returns = pd.DataFrame({'time': [dt.date(2020,1,1), dt.date(2020,1,2), dt.date(2020,1,3), dt.date(2020,1,4), dt.date(2020,1,5), dt.date(2020,1,6)],
                        'longs': [0, 1,2,3,4,3],
                        'shorts': [0, -1,-2,-3,-4,-4]})

and a chart like:
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(returns.time),
               y=list(returns.longs),
               name="Longs",
               line=dict(color="#0c56cc")))
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=list(returns.time),
               y=list(returns.shorts),
               name="Shorts",
               line=dict(color="#850411", dash="dash")))
fig.show()


When I zoom in on a particular section however I would like for the data to be renormlised using the first date in the xrange. So zooming in on the period after Jan 5 here would give me something like:

This seems to be possible using something like fig.layout.on_change as discussed here. My attempt at doing it is below but it does not appear to change the figure at all.
def renormalise_returns(returns, renorm_date):
    long_data = returns.melt(id_vars = ['time'])
    long_data.sort_values(by = 'time', inplace=True)
    cum_at_start = long_data[long_data['time'] >= renorm_date].groupby(['variable']).first().reset_index().rename(columns = {'value': 'old_value'}).drop(columns = ['time'])
    long_data2 = pd.merge(long_data, cum_at_start, how = 'left', on = ['variable'])
    long_data2['value'] = long_data2['value'] - long_data2['old_value']
    long_data2.drop(columns = ['old_value'], inplace=True)
    finn = long_data2.pivot(index = ['time'], columns = ['variable'], values = 'value').reset_index()
    return finn

fig = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=returns['time'], y=returns['longs'], name='Longs', line=dict(color="#0c56cc")),
                      go.Scatter(x=returns['time'], y=returns['shorts'], name="Shorts", line=dict(color="#850411", dash="dash"))])
def zoom(xrange):
    xrange_zoom_min, xrange_zoom_max = fig.layout.xaxis.range[0], fig.layout.xaxis.range[1]
    df2 = renormalise_returns(returns, xrange_zoom_min)
    fig = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=df2['time'], y=df2['longs']), go.Scatter(x=df2['time'], y=df2['shorts'])])

fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range')
fig.show()


First, you need to convert returns['time'] to prevent JSON serialization error with datetime data (it seems with go.Figure() Plotly handles this but with go.FigureWidget() it doesn't).
Secondly, by doing fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range'), the function callback zoom should expect 2 parameters, the first one being the layout object, and the 2nd one the observed xaxis range.
Also, in the callback you need to update the figure using an update method because by re-assigning a new figure to the fig variable then the reference to the actual (plotted) figure is lost and the change won't be reflected on the plot.
One last thing (cf. Displaying Figures Using ipywidgets) :

It is important to note that FigureWidget is not meant to use the renderers framework [...], so you should not use the show() figure method or the plotly.io.show() function on FigureWidget objects.

In fact, a FigureWidget is also an ipywidgets object. ipywidgets have their own display repr which allows them to be displayed using IPython's display framework. So at the end of the cell, using fig alone or display(fig) should represent the figure properly, the same way as fig.show() but with ipywidgets contexts enabled.
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from IPython.display import display

returns = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [dt.date(2020, 1, 1), dt.date(2020, 1, 2), dt.date(2020, 1, 3), dt.date(2020, 1, 4), dt.date(2020, 1, 5), dt.date(2020, 1, 6)],
    'longs': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3],
    'shorts': [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -4]
})

returns['time'] = returns['time'].astype(str)

def renormalise_returns(returns, renorm_date):
    long_data = returns.melt(id_vars = ['time'])
    long_data.sort_values(by = 'time', inplace=True)
    cum_at_start = long_data[long_data['time'] >= renorm_date].groupby(['variable']).first().reset_index().rename(columns = {'value': 'old_value'}).drop(columns = ['time'])
    long_data2 = pd.merge(long_data, cum_at_start, how = 'left', on = ['variable'])
    long_data2['value'] = long_data2['value'] - long_data2['old_value']
    long_data2.drop(columns = ['old_value'], inplace=True)
    finn = long_data2.pivot(index = ['time'], columns = ['variable'], values = 'value').reset_index()
    return finn

fig = go.FigureWidget([
    go.Scatter(x=returns['time'], y=returns['longs'], name='Longs', line=dict(color="#0c56cc")),
    go.Scatter(x=returns['time'], y=returns['shorts'], name="Shorts", line=dict(color="#850411", dash="dash"))
])

def zoom(layout, xrange):
    xrange_zoom_min, xrange_zoom_max = xrange
    df2 = renormalise_returns(returns, xrange_zoom_min)
    fig.update_traces(selector=dict(name='Longs'), x=df2['time'], y=df2['longs'])
    fig.update_traces(selector=dict(name='Shorts'), x=df2['time'], y=df2['shorts'])

fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range')

display(fig)


Thanks for this. I tried to changed the zoom function as you suggested but it doesnt make the zoom react as I had hoped. zooming in on a subset of dates does not appear to trigger renormalisation. Does this work on your machine?

Yes it works, but I forgot one important thing ! See revised answer. Sorry if you lost time wondering why it still doesn't work, I should have pasted the whole code yesterday directly.

Thanks but still doesn't work for me. The one change I made is rather than using IPython.display, I did change to fig.show() and also using it in streamlit.plotly(chart) but neither is any different from the case without this zoom function. Maybe there is something specific to IPython.display here?

Maybe, that's weird.. On my side I run the whole code in a single notebook cell in VS Code and it works fine with fig or display(fig), with fig.show() the callback is not triggered. I use Python 3.11.6, and for the involved packages I got : plotly 5.18.0, ipykernel 6.25.2, ipython 8.16.1, ipywidgets 8.1.1.

Yeah doing it in an ipython notebook it does work for me!. So it seems like something is wierd in fig.show() and streamlit.plotly. I guess I will file a github issue for it

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4634

I don't think it's an issue actually, go.FigureWidget is precisely meant to be used in a notebook (I assumed you were doing this in a notebook!), and as I mentioned it relies on ipywidgets which enables interactions between the frontend and the backend so that the callback can be triggered. This won't work outside of a notebook because there is no http server to allow the frontend and the backend callback to communicate.

From there you got 2 options to make it work in a browser window, 1. use Dash (which I recommend), or 2. use fig.show(post_script=js) where js is a javascript snippet that register a plotly_relayout callback (cf. Plotly.js API) and implements the renormalization callback on the clientside, which can be tricky if you don't know Plotly.js and/or are not comfortable with javascript.
